# ngCordova Camera not working in iOS

Tags: angularjs, cordova-plugins, visual-studio-cordova, ngcordova

I use ngCordova and in order to access the camera i use the below code

```
 var destinationType = navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI;
            var options = {
                quality: 50,
                destinationType: destinationType,
                sourceType: pictureSource,
                correctOrientation: true,
                encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.PNG,
            }

            var cameraPromise = $cordovaCamera.getPicture(options);
            cameraPromise.then(function (imageUri) {
                deferedPromise.resolve(imageUri);
                $cordovaCamera.cleanup();
            });
            return deferedPromise;
```

The code works fine in Android but when i run the same on iOS it takes the photo but returns to the app but when i click on view image the link seems to be broken . See below

[image]

In orde to test the changes we need to do a remote build so testing the app is difficult . Is there anything obvious that i am missing ? The File Explorer option seems to work in iOs that is image picked from the gallery is picked and on view is shown ?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0" xmlns:vs="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/2014/htmlapps" id="com.frontavenue.hseq" version="1.0.0" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" defaultlocale="en-US">
  <name>HSEQ Master</name>
  <description>HSEQ</description>
  <author href="http://cordova.io" email="dev@cordova.apache.org">frontAvenue</author>
  <content src="index.html" />
  <vs:features />
  <preference name="SplashScreen" value="screen" />
  <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="5000" />
  <preference name="windows-target-version" value="8.1" />
  <!-- Support for Cordova 5.0.0 plugin system -->
  <plugin name="cordova-plugin-whitelist" version="1" />
  <allow-intent href="http://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="https://*/*" />
  <allow-intent href="tel:*" />
  <allow-intent href="sms:*" />
  <allow-intent href="mailto:*" />
  <allow-intent href="geo:*" />
  <platform name="android">
    <allow-intent href="market:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <allow-intent href="itms:*" />
    <allow-intent href="itms-apps:*" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-36-ldpi.png" density="ldpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-48-mdpi.png" density="mdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-72-hdpi.png" density="hdpi" />
    <icon src="res/icons/android/icon-96-xhdpi.png" density="xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <!-- iOS 8.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone 6 Plus  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-3x.png" width="180" height="180" />
    <!-- iOS 7.0+ -->
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch  -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60.png" width="60" height="60" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-60-2x.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76.png" width="76" height="76" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-76-2x.png" width="152" height="152" />
    <!-- iOS 6.1 -->
    <!-- Spotlight Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40.png" width="40" height="40" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-40-2x.png" width="80" height="80" />
    <!-- iPhone / iPod Touch -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57.png" width="57" height="57" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-57-2x.png" width="114" height="114" />
    <!-- iPad -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72.png" width="72" height="72" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-72-2x.png" width="144" height="144" />
    <!-- iPhone Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small.png" width="29" height="29" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-small-2x.png" width="58" height="58" />
    <!-- iPad Spotlight and Settings Icon -->
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/ios/icon-50-2x.png" width="100" height="100" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="150" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="360" height="360" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png" width="30" height="30" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="310" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png" width="106" height="106" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png" width="70" height="70" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png" width="170" height="170" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-100.png" width="50" height="50" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/StoreLogo.scale-240.png" width="120" height="120" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png" width="310" height="150" />
    <icon src="res/icons/windows/Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png" width="744" height="360" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/ApplicationIcon.png" width="62" height="62" />
    <icon src="res/icons/wp8/Background.png" width="173" height="173" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="android">
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png" density="land-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png" density="land-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png" density="land-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png" density="land-xhdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png" density="port-hdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png" density="port-ldpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png" density="port-mdpi" />
    <splash src="res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png" density="port-xhdpi" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="ios">
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait.png" width="320" height="480" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png" width="640" height="960" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait.png" width="768" height="1024" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png" width="1536" height="2048" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape.png" width="1024" height="768" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png" width="2048" height="1536" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-568h-2x.png" width="640" height="1136" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png" width="750" height="1334" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png" width="1242" height="2208" />
    <splash src="res/screens/ios/screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png" width="2208" height="1242" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="windows">
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-100.png" width="620" height="300" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreen.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
    <splash src="res/screens/windows/SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png" width="1152" height="1920" />
  </platform>
  <platform name="wp8">
    <splash src="res/screens/wp8/SplashScreenImage.jpg" width="480" height="800" />
  </platform>
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-camera" version="1.2.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file" version="3.0.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-splashscreen" version="2.1.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-file-transfer" version="1.4.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-dialogs" version="1.2.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="cordova-plugin-network-information" version="1.1.0" />
  <vs:plugin name="de.appplant.cordova.plugin.email-composer" version="0.8.2" src="C:\Users\francisf\Downloads\cordova-plugin-email-composer-0.8.2" />
  <preference name="Fullscreen" value="False" />
  <preference name="KeepRunning" value="False" />
  <preference name="ShowTitle" value="True" />
  <preference name="InAppBrowserStorageEnabled" value="False" />
  <preference name="SuppressesIncrementalRendering" value="True" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.ionic.keyboard" version="1.0.4" src="C:\Users\francisf\Downloads\ionic-plugin-keyboard-1.0.4" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.hiddentao.cordova.filepath" version="1.0.0" src="F:\D-Drive\Softwares\Cordova_Plugins\cordova-plugin-filepath-master" />
  <vs:plugin name="com.synconset.imagepicker" version="1.0.7" src="F:\D-Drive\Softwares\Cordova_Plugins\cordova-imagePicker-1.0.7" />
  <preference name="Orientation" value="default" />
</widget>
```

Comment: did you add these two line in config.xml:

<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/camera"/>
<feature name="http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/file"/>

Comment: I have updated the config.xml in the post i have tried added your lines of code to the config.xml at the top level still same